# How to select the row containing a newly added record in a datasheet, similar to a listbox?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Previously, I was using a `ListBox` with the its `Value` property in order to select that particular row containing a newly added record from the table.

It was achieved using something like this:

```
Me.listBox.Value = DLookup("ID", "myTable", searchCriteria)
Me.listBox.Requery
```

Once I've inserted a record into `myTable`, I would call the above code to refresh the `ListBox` and select the row containing the new record.

I've since switched to a `Datasheet`, but it doesn't have a `Value` property.

I can call the following to refresh the `DataSheet`, but obviously it doesn't highlight the row containing the new record:

```
Forms!frmMyForm.datasheet_MySheet.Requery
```

What is the best way to accomplish what I've described?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to move to the record using the bookmark:

```
With datasheet_MySheet.Form
    .RecordsetClone.FindFirst searchCriteria
    If Not .RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
        .Bookmark = .RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    End If
End With
```

...where datasheet_MySheet is the name of the SubForm control (the datasheet) on the parent form.

Edit: Explanation:

`RecordsetClone` is a copy of the Form's Recordset which contains the form's data. The `FindFirst` method of the Recordset makes the matching record the current record (in that Recordset). E.g. if the `searchCriteria` was `"ID=6"` then it would move to the record where ID is 6. Setting the Form's `Bookmark` property to the `Bookmark` property of the `RecordsetClone` makes the current record on the Form (and thus the visibly selected row) the same as what was just found in the `RecordsetClone`. In other words, it finds the record in the clone and then synchronises the visible position of the datasheet with the clone.

**Why use the clone?**

Why use `Form.RecordsetClone.FindFirst` and not `Form.Recordset.FindFirst`? `FindFirst` will move to the first row if no match is found (and oddly, the `NoMatch` property returns False indicating a match when there isn't). Effects on `Form.Recordset` are visible, whereas effects on `Form.RecordsetClone` are not, so you aren't moving the selected record unless you have a match. That may or may not matter in your case.

Comment: thanks!....I like to comment this in my code, but I'm not exactly sure what it is doing as I'm fairly new to vba...can you explain a bit on what the code is doing?